# Regex for matching "everything but" a string

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match all strings EXCEPT those that contain a certain string within.  Can someone help me construct it?

For example, looking for all strings that *do not* have a, b, and c in them in that order.

So 
abasfaf3 would match, whereas 
asasdfbasc would not

Comment: Any, looking for a general regular expression that can be adapted to any engine.  I was really looking for a theoretical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in perl:

```
if($str !~ /a.*?b.*?.*c/g)
{
    print "match";
}
```

should work.

Comment: I see, so actively looking for strings that match what I'm trying to avoid,, then taking the opposite.  I can't think of why that wouldn't work...

Comment: well, you can theoretical do build a regex that matches the opposite. but that regex would be huge. The way you do that is to build a FSM, invert the end-conditions, then build a regex out of it

Comment: @Ray: Yep you got it. In this case it's easier to regex what you don't want then find the strings that dont match the regex.

Comment: the s is for substitution, which is incorrect in this case. g is for global match

Answer (score 4):

In Python:

```
>>> r = re.compile("(?!^.*a.*b.*c.*$)")
>>> r.match("abc")
>>> r.match("xxabcxx")
>>> r.match("ab ")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7bee288>
>>> r.match("abasfaf3")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7bee288>
>>> r.match("asasdfbasc")
>>>
```

Comment: I didnt downvote you. but i asked the same today. why did they downvote my neat puzzle??

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can theoretical build a regex that matches the opposite. But for longer strings, that regex would become big. The way you would do that systematically is (greatly simplified):

- Convert the regular expression into a deterministic finite automaton
- Convert the end conditions of the automaton, so that it accepts the inverted regular language
- Convert the automaton back to a regular expression by successively removing nodes from the automaton, yet keeping the behavior of it the same. Removing one node will require putting two or more regular expressions together, so that they will account for the removed node.
- If you happen to have one start node, and one end node, you are finished: The regular expression labeling the edge between them is your searched regular expression.

Practically, you can just match for the string you want *not* have in it, and invert the result. Here is what it would look like in awk:

```
echo azyxbc | awk '{ exit ($0 !~ /a.*b.*c/); }' && echo matched
```

If you are interested into this, i recommend the book "*Introduction to the Theory of Computation*" by Michael Sipser.

Answer (score 0):

in Java:

```
(?m)^a?(.(?!a[^b\r\n]*b[^\r\nc]*c))+$
```

does match

```
abasfaf3
xxxabasfaf3
```

does not match

```
asasdfbascf
xxxxasasdfbascf
```