# What's the most compact version of "match everything but these strings" in the shell or regex?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

Linux: I want to list all the files in a directory and within its subdirectories, except some strings. For that, I've been using a combination of find/grep/shell globbing. For instance, I want to list all files except those in the directories

```
./bin
./lib
./resources
```

I understand this can be done as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322392/regex-for-matching-everything-but-a-string) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611883/regex-how-to-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern). But both versions are not solving the case "everything, but this pattern" in general terms.

It seems that it is much easier to use a conditional for filtering the results, but I wonder if there is any compact and elegant way of describing this in regexp or in the shell extended globbing.

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid using "here" for link text.

Comment: Sorry, as english is not my native language I don't know the proper way. Could you please suggest any? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [bash's extglob shopt setting](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_55.html) enabled, you can exclude files with `!` in your [wildcard pattern](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_35.html). Some examples:

- Everything except bin, lib, and resources

  ```
  shopt -s extglob
  ls -Rl !(bin|lib|resources)
  ```
- Everything with an `i` in it, except bin and lib

  ```
  ls -Rl !(bin|lib|!(*i*))
  ```

  (Everything that has an `i` in it is the same as everything *except* the things that *don't* have `i`'s in them.)

Comment: The most compact. I've tried similar things, but never realized that if you put the * then anything is matched, so the way was without anything else. I wonder how this could be added to some more restrictions. Like: "everything that has an "i" except "bin" and "lib"...

Answer (score 7):

`yourcommand | egrep -v "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3"`

Comment: I wasn't aware of this switch of egrep. It is a good way. Thanks!

Comment: This will suppress all the files which happen to have pattern in their name, which might be more, then you want to suppress.

Comment: I agree with @vartec - this can be dangerous.  I prefer the prune option.

Comment: It can't be limited with end/begin of line characters? ^ and $ ? Because this option is more compact and easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Use prune option of find.

```
find . -path './bin' -prune -o -path './lib' -prune -o -path './resources' -prune -o «rest of your find params»
```